# Export several sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba, export

I'm working on a macro in my Excel File.
I want to export six worksheets as new backup files.
There are several sheets that I also don't want to export.
When I run the code as it is now there is one/two sheets that are being exported while the remaining four aren't exported.
The two exported sheets are then also being closed after they are saved as a new file.
I hope someone is able to help me and give me advice and feedback.
Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
'''


 Sub SplitWorkbook2()

Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xNWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    
        DateString = Format(Now, "mm-dd hh-mm")
        FolderName = "I:\Export\Backup\TEMPS\2021\Urenlijsten\" & " Werkbriefjes week " & Range("C4") & " " & DateString
    
MkDir FolderName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
On Error GoTo NErro

DoNotInclude = "Actions" & "Adressbook" & "Import" & "Hours_Database"
FileExtStr = ".xls"

For Each xWs In xWb.Sheets
        If InStr(DoNotInclude, xWs.Name) = 0 Then
            xWs.Copy
            Set xNWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Application.Workbooks.Count)
                With xNWb
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
                    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Range("C6") & FileExtStr
                    xNWb.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                End With
    
        End If

    Next xWs
   
    

NErro: xWb.Activate
    

xWb.Activate
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is a sample sheet name that isn't being exported but should be?

Comment: A few of the sheets would be: "AZ" "Start 1" "Start 2". the formulas in the sheets need to be in the backup be set to values instead of formulas.

Comment: Note that `With xNWb` is doing absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

### Export Worksheets

- Not tested.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitWorkbook2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DoNotInclude As Variant
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FolderName As String

    FolderName = "I:\Export\Backup\TEMPS\2021\Urenlijsten\" & " Werkbriefjes week " & Range("C4") & " " & DateString
    FileExtStr = ".xlsx" ' ??? not '.xls'
    DateString = Format(Now, "mm-dd hh-mm")
    
    DoNotInclude = Array("Actions" & "Adressbook" & "Import" & "Hours_Database")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir FolderName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, DoNotInclude, 0)) Then
            ws.Copy
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
                .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
                xFile = FolderName & "\" & .Range("C6") & FileExtStr
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .Parent.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                .Parent.Close
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    'wb.FollowHyperlink FolderName ' open in Windows File Explorer
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. It is almost working it is giving a run time error #1004: SaveAs method of workbook class failed. Is it causing this error as the xFile path is wrong or is there any way fix this?

Comment: @Glen - what is the output of `Debug.Print xFile` in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Maybe `MkDir` is failing. Try to out-comment the two `On Error` lines to see what happens, and later uncomment them again. If you're sticking with `.xls` then you have to replace `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` with something found on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

Comment: @VBasic2008 when I change it back to .xls and change the xlOpenXMLWorkbook it gets the same error. In the Immediate Window it displays nothing?

Comment: Have you tested my file? Also, you haven't reported what the value of xFile is (BigBen's suggestion).

Comment: it seems as if the first file saves and then the seccond wants to save but remains open?

Comment: Instead of `.Parent.Close` try `.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 somehow the first saves allright then the seccond doesn't save and returns the error. It is as if it then doesnt save it with the right file format? I am using xlsx and the xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Comment: The line `xFile = FolderName & "\" & .Range("C6") & FileExtStr` assumes that there is a valid file name in cell `C6` of the current source worksheet. If there is no value `.xlsx` cannot be saved as a file. Try to add the line `Debug.Print "Curr = " & xFile` right below the previous mentioned line and investigate the issue.

Comment: @VBasic2008  Will  the range be variable so if it export sheet 1 "AZ" in cell C6 it contains the name of the sheet "AZ" so it saves as a seperate workbook named AZ in the assigned folder. The next sheet needs to be saved as "Start 1"as the sheet is named Start 1. in sheet start 1 the cell C6 also has the name of the sheet. I hope you understand what I mean